# How can I calculate the potential energy stored by a playing swing?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, potential-energy, estimation, oscillators

So, for normal scenes of potential energy the equation would just be $E_p= mgh$ (Mass, Gravity, Height), but in this particular scene, swings have a  particular angle to it when you swing it upwards. So my question in resume is how to calculate the potential energy of a swing.

Comment: You are thinking that the string has energy in it too? Like the string has mass?

Answer (score 1):

Work done of a conservative vector field (such as gravity) force, depends **only on body path endpoints**, it can be stated mathematically as :
$$ \oint _{C}\mathbf {F} \cdot d{\mathbf {r} }=0. $$
I.e. path integral over closed loop is zero, so total work done is zero. Thus only swing heights matters, it has nothing to do with angles or exact swing path how it travels over time. At each point swing has potential energy :
$$ U = mg(h-h_0) $$
where $h_0$ is swing height in it's lowest position relative to Earth surface.

Answer (score -1):

You can model the equation for calculating the potential energy of the swing, which can be considered a pendulum, as to

$$h=L\cdot(1-\cos(\theta))$$

Try this link: https://blogs.bu.edu/ggarber/interlace/pendulum/energy-in-a-pendulum/ for further reference.

Comment: Hello! I have edited your answer using MathJax (LaTeX) math typesetting. For future posts, you can refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!